# How to solve this issue `Could not load file or assembly 'xxxx' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, opencv

I am new to Asp.net I have done one simple application in Asp.net with `OpenCV` cross library for image comparison.
    Initially i set the project platform as `x86` But when i tries to change that to `x64` format it will show this error

```
Could not load file or assembly xxxx or one of its dependencies.
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
```

How to solve this any suggestions?

Comment: Did you make sure that you are Importing the 64 bit Dll instead of the 321 bit one?

Comment: where should i import this in my project.

Comment: is might be OpenCV is not cross-platform but only specific to 32Bits. Try to check if they have available version for 64Bit

Comment: Right click on **References** select **Add reference** select the **browse button** and navigate to the 64bit Dll. I do not have OpenCV on my computer so I can not tell you exactly where to go( another 42% to go on the download).

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** It really **depends on several facts** and there might be two things that you may probably want to check in the first round of investigation:

1- Start by checking if you are referencing an assembly which in turn referencing an old version of unity. for example let's say you have an assembly called ServiceLocator.dll which needs an old version of Unity assembly, now when you reference the ServiceLocator you should provide it with the old version of Unity, and that makes the problem.

2- Look for the output folder where all projects build their assemblies, it might probably has an old version of unity.

In addition, you can use [FuseLogVw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) application to find out who is loading the old assemblies, just define a path for the log, and run your solution, then check (in FuseLogvw) the first line where the Unity assembly is loaded, double click it and see the calling assembly, and here you go.

Comment: Yes, definitely look at `fuselogvw`. It will indicate the fully qualified assembly names and paths searched.

Comment: Sorry.. @EIYusubov I didn't understand What you said still I am new to  asp.net Please provide clear description if possible any link thanks advance